# Reuse PyQt window design across multiple instances

Tags: python, class, pyqt5

I have designed a window in QT designer and then converted it to Python code. Then I created class A and Class B which inherit from PYQT code. Then I create the third class call it C and inherit from class A and B.

```
from QTfile import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
class A(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.A1= Ui_MainWindow()
    self.A1.setupUi(self)

class B(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.B1= Ui_MainWindow()
    self.B1.setupUi(self)
```

Now the problem is when I want to use `super().__init__()` function, I only can initiate one of them.

```
class C( A,B):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

If I use `A.__init__()` and `B.__init__()`, it works again only for one classes

```
class C( A,B):
def __init__(self):
    A.__init__()
    B.__init__()
```

Now the question is how can I initiate the multiple classes?

Comment: PyQt doesn't support this kind of multiple inheritance, and, in any case, using it in this way doesn't make much sense, since `setupUi` should always be called only once (and each call would theoretically "overwrite" the previous ui). In any case, I'm afraid you're having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am very new to PyQt. is it good approach if I design first ui using Qt designer and convert code into python, and later code minor enhance if require. will  it work? how is experience if you are planning to handle such large project

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the design in multiple window instances, you can try the following:

```
class BaseWindow(Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

class A(BaseWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class B(BaseWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```